# mDNS on a large domain

Tags: networking, domain, subnet, mdns, zeroconf

I'm working remotely on a corporate VPN and I can connect to our intranet webpage using the server IP address. I read it may be possible to instead resolve using `http://servername.local/ourwebsite` where `servername.local` replaces the IP.

- Our server apparently had an avahi-daemon process running
- I opened up UDP port 5353.
- I installed bonjour on my Windows client (win7).
- Problem: I am **unable to discover/resolve the server using the machine name**

mDNS seems a good solution at the home network level, but is it not working because I am on a different subnet? Or perhaps I need to install more avahi software on the server?

P.S. I understand I can edit my hosts file but this is undesirable as I don't expect all my colleagues want to edit theirs. Similarly, I don't expect them to change their DNS server configurations.

Comment: Does your company not run an internal DNS server for things like this? The VPN client should be able to manage the system configuration and setup DNS resolution correctly.

Comment: @Attie wouldn't that require us to change our DNS configuration to use the company DNS server? I just checked the Cisco VPN client settings, no mention of DNS anywhere so I'm not even sure the DNS isn't leaking outside the VPN.

Comment: The Cisco VPN client has no settings because the Cisco VPN _server_ has all of those settings. (We actually use ocserv as the server but it's definitely able to send DNS server addresses to the client.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular DNS would be the best choice, and it would most likely be the solution that needs *least* amount of work from your colleagues. Your corporate network probably has a DNS domain already, so the remaining steps are:

1. Add a standard subdomain for your intranet website.
2. If the domain is private (made-up or just not publicly delegated), then tell everyone to use corp DNS as long as they're connected to the corp network.

   But if the domain is public (global), then others can just continue using the same DNS server they're already using. Yes you can put private IP addresses in public DNS.
3. If you don't want to do either, then set up a "reverse proxy" server on the corp network – give it a 'normal' IP address and configure as a frontend for your internal webserver. Of course, the proxy can still have a firewall to limit which *clients* are allowed to access it.

> mDNS seems a good solution at the home network level, but is it not working because I am on a different subnet?

Indeed – 1) most routers are not configured to forward multicasts; 2) mDNS uses a "link-local" group which is *not meant* to be forwarded, and 3) on top of that, Avahi even deliberately sets TTL=1 on its mDNS packets so that they would never be forwarded even if the router *did* support it.

> I don't expect them to change their DNS server configurations.

I guess I have two contradictory opinions about that:

- On the one hand, if they're connected to the corporate network, then they ought to be using the corporate DNS server, whether they want it or not.

  This applies also to VPNs. Most VPN systems are able to automatically provide DNS configuration as part of the standard connection process, so as soon as your colleagues connect to the corp VPN their computer should automatically start using corp DNS.

  (It is sometimes even possible to use "split" DNS, where certain domains are resolved using corp DNS but everything else still goes through the user's normal ISP DNS server.)
- But on the other hand, DNS was meant to be *global* once upon a time – its contents weren't supposed to change depending on what server you're using. It might be stupid of me, but I would much rather just create a subdomain that can be resolved world-wide and avoid the whole "changing DNS servers" problem from the beginning.

  If you don't want to put internal IPs in public DNS, then a "reverse proxy" server would avoid that issue. The subdomain could then point to the reverse proxy's public address, hiding the actual server.

Comment: Not sure I understand option 3, you'd still need to type the IP of the reverse proxy instead of the website IP?

Comment: Oh and we're not using the server internal IP. It has a public IP that we use, and a firewall currently blocking non-local incoming IPs.

Comment: Not if you add the _reverse proxy_ to DNS. (In many cases, that's easier than adding the internal webserver to DNS directly. The same reverse proxy can even act as a frontend for _many_ intranet webservers.)

Comment: Oh, if your server already has a public IP, then there's absolutely no problem with just adding it to DNS already. It's normal to have public subdomains even for intranet-only websites. **It won't affect your firewall blocks.**

Comment: But to add it to public DNS I'd need to buy a domain like `mymachine.com`, whereas I'd prefer the url to be just `mymachine`. I guess I'll talk to our IT guys about adding it to our corp DNS, but if mDNS just worked I'd have been happier. I like decentralized network technology.

Comment: Unfortunately, these days multicast barely works on plain Ethernet LANs (although that's more of a fault with multicast-related smarts in switches and APs)... Although the simple mDNS is at least more reliable than election-based NetBIOS NBNS of Win98 era, but I would still not even try to get it work through proprietary VPN technologies.

Comment: One more thing -- DHCP as well as many (though not all) VPN systems can actually deploy the "DNS search suffix" parameter to clients, which would let you use the short name anyway. For example, if you get `mymachine.example.corp` added to DNS, and if the VPN system (or LAN DHCP) provides `example.corp` as the "DNS suffix" to your colleagues, then they can indeed visit `http://mymachine/`.

Comment: Thanks, great additions to a helpful answer!